# Scraping multiple directories from the same website in R

Tags: r

I am trying to I am trying to make a database [similar to this one](http://mikelee.co/posts/milb-scraper-with-rvest/), but with a different table.

I have a list of playerids (in the mbp_example.csv file) and I am looping through each playerids website and pulling the table "2016 Player Batting Splits" ([example here](http://www.baseball-reference.com/register/player.cgi?id=confor001mic&type=bgl&year=2016)). However, I keep getting multiple error types.

I have listed my code below:

```
c('rvest','dplyr') -> packages #installs packages
lapply(packages, library, character.only = T)

id <- read.csv("mbp.csv")
url <- "http://www.baseball-reference.com/register/player.cgi?id="
ids=c(id)
stats_table <- '#batting_splits_milb.sortable.stats_table'
stats_id <- paste0(stats_table,' a')
minors_splits <- data.frame()
for (ids in ids) {
html <- paste(url,ids,"&type=bgl&year=2016",sep="")
read_html(html) %>%
html_nodes(stats_table) %>%
html_table(header = T) %>%
data.frame() %>%
tbl_df() -> df
df <- df[1:nrow(df),]
df$ids <- c(ids)
minors_splits <- rbind(minors_splits,df)
}
```

This gives me the following error(s):

```
Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) : 
  expecting a single value
```

or

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

Comment: I guess you need to find out which id's cause the problem, since I cannot reproduce the errors when I try it on 2 id's.

Comment: Any idea how I would figure that out? Would running (for example) 100 at a time be a good start?

Comment: or run it and get the current id when it is stuck. Also i think you need to make `for (ids in ids)` into `for (id  in ids)` and use `id` in your loop code. Then you can see the content of `id` when the script halts.

Comment: Ohhh. I got it! Thanks man.